# Default method on a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

There is a way in JS to execute a default method when I call a instance?

Example: Let's assume I have the following class named `MyClass`, then I start a instance of this class named `foo`, I want that when I call `foo` execute the `default` method of `MyClass`.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.props = {
        question: 'live, universe, everything',
        answer: 42
    }
  }

  default () {
    return this.props
  }

  hello () {
    return 'hello world'
  }
}
const foo = new MyClass()

// execute the default method
console.log(foo) // log: {question: 'live, universe, everything', answer: 42}

// execute hello method
console.log(foo.hello()) // log: hello world
```

Comment: I don't believe JavaScript has a feature like this, although someone more knowledgeable with the spec than me might prove me wrong. That said, is it really that much more hassle to write `foo.props`?

Comment: mind if we ask what is the use case?

Comment: I'm confused, how would you know when you wanted `foo` the object and `foo` the instance of `MyClass`? What happens if `props` contains a method `hello()`?

Comment: @Shih-MinLee I was just wondering if it was posible, but as Joe Clay and RGraham stated maybe this is not a good idea.

Comment: @rog3r It's certainly possible, it just prohibits some functionality

Comment: FWIW Visual Basic has a feature like this. (I forget the syntax, I've never used it.) I was just working on a program where I create a class Foo and then a class FooList with field list which is an array of Foo's. I'm constantly wringing fooList.list[x]. It would be nice if there was a way to abbreviate that to fooList[x]. But yeah, the fact that in JS you can assign a function to a variable makes that ambiguous. (In VB, to assign a function to a variable you have to say "AdddressOf function", which eliminates the ambiguity.) Yes, it's pure fluff, handy in some cases but easy to do without.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only default method that is called when instantiating an object is the `constructor`.

In ES6 you can return whatever you want from the constructor so the following code is valid:

```
    class MyClass {
        constructor () {
              var instance = {
                    question: 'live, universe, everything',
                    answer: 42,
                    hello: () => {  return 'hello world' }
              }
              return instance;
        }
     }
```

You can then instantiate an object like this:

```
var foo = new MyClass();
foo.hello(); //Hello world
console.log(foo.question);    //live, universe, everything
console.log(foo.answer);    //42
```